# Error using cv2.equalizeHist

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I am trying to equalize the histogram of a gray level image using the following code:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("myimage.png")
eq = cv2.equalizeHist(im)
```

The following exception is raised:

```
error: (-215) CV_ARE_SIZES_EQ(src, dst) && CV_ARE_TYPES_EQ(src, dst) && CV_MAT_TYPE(src->type) == CV_8UC1 in function cvEqualizeHist
```

The version of opencv is `2.4.2`

Any guesses?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

cv2.equalizeHist only works on grayscale ( 1 channel ) images. either:

```
im = cv2.imread("myimage.png", 0)        # load as grayscale
```

or:

```
im = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # or convert
```

Answer (score 13):

I got the same error, here is the solution:

1. Thanks to: zwep ([Error using cv2.equalizeHist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153271/error-using-cv2-equalizehist)) and 
   Reti43 ([Conversion of image type int16 to uint8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866586/conversion-of-image-type-int16-to-uint8))
2. Error

The error is because the dtype of the array as zwep said.
But we can't just use `img.astype(np.uint8)` or `np.uint8(img)`; it will change the image. Here is the result.

- Raw Image(img):

[image]

```
plt.imshow(np.uint8(img),cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

[image]

3. Solution

   ```
   img1=np.uint8(cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX))
   plt.imshow(cv2.equalizeHist(img1),cmap=plt.cm.gray)
   ```

[image]

PS: Adaptive histogram equalization is better for MRI.

```
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
plt.imshow(clahe.apply(img1),cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else stumbled across this but is already using grayscale ($M \times N$) ndarrays... There can be another problem.

When you use `cv2.imread()` it reads in the image as a numpy ndarray using `dtype=np.uint8`. However, when I use any other method it can be stored as a `dtype=np.uint16` which will trigger the following warning

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (_src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3))) in cv::equalizeHist, file C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\histogram.cpp, line 3913
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\histogram.cpp:3913: error: (-215) _src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) in function cv::equalizeHist
```

Solution:

```
img_int8 = img.astype(np.uint8)
```

EDIT: might be doing something wrong though... because the output now gives strange results in some cases of transformation.

Comment: Maybe you need to scale your data so it fits in 8 bits?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem too. This is because your image is in BGR even if  it looks like it is in grayscale.
What you can do about it is:

1. first convert the image from grayscale to bgr.
2. use the image equilization function.
3. Convert the image back to bgr.
4. Tadaaaa!

I'll show you my code

```
# reading image
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Showing the orignal image
plt.imshow(image)
plt.title('Low-contrast256.tif')
plt.show()

# Displaying a histogram
plt.hist(image.ravel(),256,[0,256])
plt.title('Histogram of the orignal image')
plt.show()

# Converting image to grayscale 
image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Histogram equilization
image = cv2.equalizeHist(image)

# Converting image back to BGR
image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Showing the equilized image
plt.imshow(image)
plt.title('Equilized Low-contrast256.tif')
plt.show()

# Displaying a histogram
plt.hist(image.ravel(),256,[0,256])
plt.title('Histogram of the equilized image')
plt.show()
```