# Conversion of image type int16 to uint8

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have an image with data type `int16`.
So when I have to convert its range to 0-255, I got two ways to do that in Python.

1) Use `numpy.uint8` function directly

2) Use OpenCV `cv2.normalize` function with 0-255 range and then use `numpy.uint8`.

In Matlab, we directly get the conversion using `uint8` function. 
In

Also in second case, I used `NORM_MINMAX` and the range of intensity values gets changed to `0-4`.

What is the correct way to do the conversion?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All of these do different things.

`np.uint8` considers only the lowest byte of your number. It's like doing `value & 0xff`.

```
>>> img = np.array([2000, -150, 11], dtype=np.int16)
>>> np.uint8(img)
array([208, 106,  11], dtype=uint8)
```

---

`cv2.normalize` with the `cv2.NORM_MINMAX` norm type normalises your values according to the [normalisation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing))

```
img_new = (img - img.min()) * ((max_new - min_new) / (img.max() - img.min())) + min_new
```

It effectively changes one range to another and all the values in the between are scaled accordingly. By definition the original min/max values become the targetted min/max values.

```
>>> cv2.normalize(img, out, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
array([255,   0,  19], dtype=int16)
```

---

`uint8` in Matlab simply saturates your values. Everything above 255 becomes 255 and everything below 0 becomes 0.

```
>> uint8([2000 -150 11])

ans =

  255    0   11
```

If you want to replicate Matlab's functionality, you can do

```
>>> img[img > 255] = 255
>>> img[img < 0] = 0
```

---

Which one you want to use depends on what you're trying to do. If your int16 covers the range of your pixel values and you want to rescale those to uint8, then `cv2.normalize` is the answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up... I want to scaled the intensities. So first I have to use cv2.normalize then np.uint8. Right?

Comment: @user3515225 Yes, though you can do it in one step if you pass the argument `dtype=cv2.CV_8U` in `cv2.normalize`.

Comment: [`np.clip()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html#numpy-clip) performs the Matlab saturating behavior your mention. Also worth checking out for converting to `uint8` is [`cv2.convertScaleAbs()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=convertscale#convertscaleabs).

Answer (score 2):

the simply way to convert data format is to use the following formula. In this case it is possible to convert any array to a new custom format.

```
# In the case of image, or matrix/array conversion to the uint8 [0, 255] 
# range

Import numpy as np

new_data = (newd_ata - np.min(new_data)) * ((255 - 0) / (np.max(new_data) - 
np.new_data))) + 0
```